# Magento 2.3.2 - PWA venia theme installed and working, Now how to use it as my default theme, without running yarn commands

Tags: magento2.3, pwa, pwa-studio, venia, magento2.3.2

Magento 2.3.2: PWA venia theme installed and working,
Now how to use it as my default theme, without running yarn commands.

I want to make it as my default theme for desktop or when i browse through mobile this theme will automatically applies...

Currently i need to run these commands

```
1. yarn run build
2. yarn run watch:venia
```

then a new url created and i can only see the venia theme on that url..

All suggestions appreciated...